# Refreshing a directive after updating the configuration

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-directive

I am a bit confused about how to "redraw" a directive once one of the values that I pass to it has been updated.

What I have is a directive that draws a chart depending on a configuration (a JSON) that I pass to it as a scope parameter. In the controller of the view that contains the directive I can update this configuration and I want to update the directive when the new configuration is updated by the user.

The configuration JSON looks like:

```
$scope.configuration = {
    widget: {
        range: {
            maximum: 0,
            minimum: -20
        }
    }
}
```

And the directive looks like:

```
<my-chart configuration configuration="configuration"></my-chart>
```

So when I update the configuration I want the directive to refresh the content (like initialise it again).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use $scope.$watch, or $scope.$watchCollection(). Here is the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Your code can be like this

```
    $scope.$watchCollection('$scope.configuration.widget.range', function reInit(values){
init(values)
});
```

> **$watchCollection(obj, listener)**; Shallow watches the properties of an
>   object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays,
>   this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies
>   watching the properties). If a change is detected, the listener
>   callback is fired.